# Am I doing something wrong in this API call?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is the code:

```
 async createTemplate({ commit }, data) {
      console.log("CREATE TEMPLATE data STORE.JS: " + JSON.stringify(data));
      return await API.put(
                "asulink",
                "/scheduler/schedule",
                {
                  "schedule_name": "MJ Test 3",
                  "public": "true",
                  "local_times": [
                    1200,1230,1300,1330,1400,1430
                  ]
                }
              ).then((response) => {
                console.log("API.PUT ADD A SCHEDULE"+JSON.stringify(response))
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                window.console.log("Error occured", err);
              });
    },
```

If I make this API call I get a 400 error. The error says: Please send a valid JSON body.
But if I copy the above JSON body and make the same PUT API call using OpenAPI I get a 200.
I am not sure whats going on.

And this is not an axios call, but a Amplify API.put call.

Comment: Does the object need to be `{ body: { "schedule_name" ... } }`?

Comment: "And this is not an axios call, but a Amplify API.put call." — So why did you tag it with [tag:axios]?!

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thank you very much. I don't understand why was this an issue, when other API calls are working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation says something else. You need to send the request in body.

check out this link https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/update/q/platform/js#put-data

```
async createTemplate({ commit }, data) {
      console.log("CREATE TEMPLATE data STORE.JS: " + JSON.stringify(data));
      return await API.put(
                "asulink",
                "/scheduler/schedule",
                {"body": {
                  "schedule_name": "MJ Test 3",
                  "public": "true",
                  "local_times": [
                    1200,1230,1300,1330,1400,1430
                  ]
                }, "headers": {}}
              ).then((response) => {
                console.log("API.PUT ADD A SCHEDULE"+JSON.stringify(response))
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                window.console.log("Error occured", err);
              });
    },
```